# Adding a subclassed UIViewController doesn't allow any imports in .h or .m

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ide

I have added a new class that subclasses UIViewController. For some reason, I cannot import any other frameworks or custom classes into the .h file. And oddly enough, in

```
@interface TestViewController : UIViewController
```

The UIViewController is not colored to signify it's a class (I've changed my color scheme, not sure what the default color is supposed to be), it's acting like it's just some text I typed in.

In the default viewcontroller, I can import anything I need, but not in my class:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried? `#import "MyClass.h"` should work. For frameworks, use the bracket syntax like UIKit is using.

Comment: Do you actually get build errors, or is it just the syntax highlighting? They're not actually the same system. The highlighting can be indicative of problems in your code, but it's not perfect. If you have build errors, please include them in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try these things -

1. Can you do a dry build and see if there are any build errors. Just press `⌘ b`. If there are build errors xcode auto-complete does not work. Fix the errors and try again.
2. Sometimes I have noticed xcode autocomplete just gives up for no comprehensible reason. All you can do is EXIT Xcode and restart.
3. Clean Build your project and try running your code. This would empty all caches, clean your build folder etc. I have found this to be helpful sometimes. i.e. `⌘ shift k` followed by `⌘ b` or `⌘ r`
4. Again sometimes xcode codesense just gives up. Open Organizer then Project Tab. Clear the "Derived Data". Xcode should re-index your project then and codesense should work if there are no build errors.

Cant think of any other reason for this to not work.

Comment: yup! I have found xcode IDE to be a bit moody compared to some of the other mature programming environments.